# Find task by ID in ActiveCollab

Tags: api, activecollab

I'm looking to get a task by ID. I have a support ticket system that submits to ActiveCollab and I would like to be able to close out a task. I currently store the project id and the task id but if the task moves projects I am unable to retrieve the task. Is there a way to find a task by the id?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, tasks can be accessed via projects only, so both `project_id` and `task_id` are required arguments.

Comment: Is there any plan for this not to be the case?